# Importing external module with ES6 syntax and absolute path

Tags: import, typescript

So I have a project that looks something like this:

```
app/
  bin/
  lib/
  src/
    main/
      submodule.ts
    utilities/
      common.ts
    main.ts
    tsconfig.json
  gulpfile.js
```

and `app/src/main/submodule.ts` needs to import `app/src/utilities/common.ts`. I am trying to use the ES6 syntax for this. Thus I expect something like this in `submodule.ts`:

```
import {common} from '/utilities/common';
```

Where the root `/` is `app/src/` since that is where `tsconfig` is found. Yes, `app/src/utilities/common.ts` does export a module named `common`.

The problem is that I get "cannot find module '/utilities/common'" errors. I have tried a variety of things:

- `utilities/common`
- `/src/utilities/common`
- `/app/src/utilities/common`

None of these work. A relative path of `../utilities/common` does work, but relative paths for common modules is a maintenance nightmare.

It may be worth noting that I just updated from TS 1.5 to 1.6: using `utilities/common` had worked in 1.5. I cannot find any mention of a breaking change along these lines in the 1.6 notes, though.

I mention the `gulpfile.ts` and other folders because ultimately I want Gulp to get the TS files from `src` and put the compiled JS files in `bin`. I am reasonably confident that I have correctly configured Gulp for this, using `gulp-typescript`, but for completion's sake, here are my `tsconfig.json` and `gulpfile.js`.

- `tsconfig.json`

  ```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
          "module": "commonjs",
          "target": "es5",
          "experimentalDecorators": true,
          "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
          "noEmitOnError": true
      },
      "filesGlob": [
          "./**/*.ts",
          "!./typings/**/*.ts"
      ]
  }
  ```
- `gulpfile.js`

  ```
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var ts   = require('gulp-typescript');
  var less = require('gulp-less');
  var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

  var merge = require('merge2');
  var path  = require('path');

  var tsProject = ts.createProject('src/tsconfig.json', { noExternalResolve: true });

  gulp.task('html', function () {
      gulp.src([
              'src/**/*.html',
          ])
          .pipe(gulp.dest('bin'));
  });

  gulp.task('typescript', function () {
      tsProject.src()
          .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
          .pipe(ts(tsProject))
          .js
          .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('bin'));
  });

  gulp.task('less', function () {
      gulp.src([
              'src/**/*.less',
          ])
          .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
          .pipe(less())
          .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
          .pipe(gulp.dest('bin'))
  });

  gulp.task('default', ['html', 'typescript', 'less']);
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved this. Per [What's New](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-adjustments-in-module-resolution-logic), 1.6 changed module resolution to behave like Node's. I have not yet investigated Node's module resolution to determine if a fix is possible using that behavior, but I have found a workaround:

The old behavior can be triggered by specifying `"moduleResolution": "classic"` in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Module resolution is performed relative to the current file if the path starts with `./` or `../`.

Here is a quick example using:

```
/
/src/
/src/thing.ts
/main/
/main/submodule.ts
/utilities/
/utilities/common.ts
```

So the correct statement to import `common.ts` into `submodule.ts` would be:

```
import {common} from '../utilities/common';
```

You can also use the following root-path (note that there is no leading `/` or any `.`s here):

```
import {common} from 'src/utilities/common';
```

This works for me in Visual Studio code, with the parent folder of `src` opened as the working folder. In my case I am targeting ES5 with UMD modules.

[image: It Works!]

You can also resolve a module if it can be found by traversing up from the current location (this is a feature of NodeJS). So you can import `thing.ts` into `submodule.ts` using:

```
import {something} from 'thing';
```

The resolver will check the current folder, then the parent, then the parent's parent... and so on.

## Absolute vs Relative Paths

When it comes to links on web pages, I'm in agreement with you that absolute paths are easier to maintain, especially where resources are shared at multiple levels.

When it comes to modules, I'm not sure I see the same maintenance problem as the paths here are "relative to the file that the import statement appears in" not relative to the web page. I wonder if this may be the application of a very sensible rule in the wrong place.

Comment: Moved comments into answer.

Comment: Your screenshot matches what I'm looking to achieve (the `src` in the path will give me trouble later but that's not part of this question), but VS Code gives me an error for this same set-up. I'm using version 0.9.1, with TypeScript 1.6.2; is that the same with you?

Comment: Yes - 0.9.1 of Visual Studio Code, TypeScript 1.6.2. Is there any chance you have another version of the compiler still on your machine that might be getting picked up?

Comment: If that were the case, I would expect it to work simply because it *used to work* before I updated. I do have (several) other versions of `tsc` installed, but 1.6 is definitely the version in my path, found by PowerShell, and used by Visual Studio 2015. I'll try playing with removing the old ones to see if it makes things suddenly work, but I'm dubious. Unfortunately, cannot do that right now.

Comment: Stuck my old TypeScript compilers into the Recycle Bin; no change. As for your last section there, as the name `utilities/` might indicate, I have a number of shared, common utility functions that are used throughout my project. Counting the number of `../` every given file needs to reach root is ugly and messy, and makes re-organizing files unnecessarily painful. I absolutely stand by my insistence that absolute paths are necessary here. For things in my folder or in a subfolder of mine, I can see advantages for relative paths, but as soon as you have to go up and down a different branch, no.